# Secure Static website hosted on S3 using custom SSL in Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

My subdomain configured in route53 dev.abc.com goes to unsecure connection and I want to make it available via https only.

Steps I have done:

- Get a custom SSL certificate from AWS ACM and add cname records in my route53 hosted zone.
- Made a cloudfront distribution that uses custom ssl cert created in step 1 where the name of ssl certificate and the alternate domain name match(dev.abc.com)
- Mark Redirect HTTP to HTTPS behaviour in cloudfront
- Add an A record for dev.abc.com to the cloudfront distribution by adding an alias record

I have reviewed multiple guides being new to AWS infra and have not come accross a solutions. I have also found that If your Amazon S3 bucket is configured as a website endpoint, you can't configure CloudFront to use HTTPS to communicate with your origin because Amazon S3 doesn't support HTTPS connections in that configuration here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-cloudfront-to-s3-origin.html

Is there any way to make my url accessible via https?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps you have done sound generally ok, I guess the issue is in some detail that you've missed or haven't described.

Be aware not to mix steps and stick to one path: Either "S3 static hosting mode" or "OAC/OAI" path. Mixing both will lead to confusions and a not working solution.

Step-by-step guide if S3 is in static hosting mode [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/).

Step-by-step guide if S3 shouldn't be in static hosting mode and everything should pass through CloudFront ([here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-access-to-amazon-s3/)).

Comment: My s3 bucket is intended to host the front end of my application hence web hosting is turned on. Is there any way to route traffic over HTTPS to my website in this configuration?

PS: I have exactly followed the steps shared the in above-mentioned AWS Guide specifically the steps under the "Using a website endpoint as the origin, with anonymous (public) access allowed" title. They explicitly mention an s3 bucket with static web hosting turned on. I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: These steps do work and are tried and proven (have them done so myself). Maybe remove the S3 and CF and restart from scratch to be sure that no other configuration is applied. AWS can be wast and configuration can even hide from the console...

Comment: Sorry for asking again, but the documentation I have linked says it won't work with HTTPS in static hosting mode. You yourself mentioned that it shouldn't be in static web hosting mode. 
The guide you have linked says otherwise and hence the confusion.
I have redone the CF,route53 and AWS Config at least 4 times by now.

Comment: I've linked both solutions, best practice (IMHO) is the non-static-hosting version, but both work and I have done them multiple times. If there are still errors you should update the question with detailed error descriptions or contact AWS support.

Comment: I was able to make it work by **Using a REST API endpoint as the origin, with access restricted by an OAC or an OAI** portion in the first guide. The main issue was this whole confusion regarding static hosting mode vs REST API configuration.
Your response is also misleading in a way that the guide you link clearly says that it's not possible in static web hosting mode.
this is one of the key differences between REST API endpoints vs website enabled endpoints [reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteEndpoints.html)

Comment: I've updated the answer to be clear to stick to one path OAC/S3 static hosting. Thanks. I guess in my mind the OAC one is the only path and I excluded the other from my mind.